# Python Value Optimization - LP, Genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, linear-programming

**Hope everyone is ok and safe at home!**

I have the following problem:

A number of "N" machines, and each machine can have a number of "M" states. Each state have different power level. My goal is to calculate what state each machine needs to be set to be under a load threshold.

For example, let's say that I have 5 different machines and the following states:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Machine | State 1 | State 2 | State 3 | State 4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |    1000 |     600 |     400 | 50      |
|       2 |    1500 |     800 |     500 | 60      |
|       3 |    1000 |     500 |     400 | 50      |
|       4 |     500 |     300 |     100 | ----    |
|       5 |     700 |     600 |     100 | ----    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**note that machine 4 and 5 don't have state 4

Assuming that everything is operating on state 1, the total power would be 4700W.

But let's say that I want to drop 700W, so the new operating needs to be <= 4000W. Of course there are many possible solutions to that, I can operate machine 3 and 4 on state 2, or only operate machine 2 on state 2, I really don't care what solution I get (for now) but I need to calculate this FAST!

**obs: the real data can have around 1 to 2 k machines.

Can I solve this with LP? how can I frame this problem to be able to solve it?

## Things I already tried:

1) I implemented a genetic algorithm to solve this, but performance was really poor, it took minutes to solve the problem, maybe I had a poor implementation, maybe it was the number of variables.

2) I tried to brute force and generate all possible permutations and generate a big lookup table, but machines and state can change too often so that is not a valid solution.

3) Current implementation starts all machines on state 1, and decrease a machine, state by state sorting all states from lower to higher. It is running pretty fast, but some times the result is not optimal.

## Update (03/30)

My goal, if not clear, is to calculate a set of states for each machine in order to minimize the difference between their power and a SET TARGET.

For the example above, if I plot the possible states and the total power I get something like this:

[image]

So If I want to operate both machines (1 and 2) at a maximum power of 3000, I need to operate both at state 1, because the maximum power of that state is 2500.

If I want to operate both machines (1 and 2) at a maximum power of 2300 I need to operate machine 1 at state 2 and machine 1 at state 1.

In other words, I need to be under the set load, and at the maximum possible power.

Comment: I'm my opinion you don't have defined clearly an objective function to minimize or maximize to find a solution using LP. The total power value looks like a constraint rather than an objective function.

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget anything? Without additional constraints, this looks not that interesting. As currently stated: just pick the smallest state for each machine / smallest value for each row. This is the global-optimum of minimizing power-usage and will stay the global-opt as there is no process of dynamic modification described. A future query x and a future query y will be treated equal as you already know the global optimum and every query is a simple if-statement. If you have side-constraints or other stuff: just use constraint-programming. But details matter then...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the objective function for me is the difference with the set power to the "possible new power" calculated. 
What I want to do is to have a set target, and calculate where the machines need to be in order to minimize that difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using a simple MIP-model and solving with PULP:

```
from pulp import *

# DATA
power = [
    [1000, 600, 400, 50], 
    [1500, 800, 500, 60], 
    [1000, 500, 400, 50], 
    [500, 300, 100, 0], 
    [700, 600, 100, 0]]
target_power = 2500
max_machines = 3

# VARIABLES
N = range(len(power))
S = range(len(power[0]))
x = [[pulp.LpVariable("x_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j), 0, 1, 'Binary') for j in S] for i in N]

# OBJECTIVE
prob = LpProblem("Power problem", LpMinimize)
prob += target_power - lpSum([power[i][j]*x[i][j] for j in S for i in N])

# CONSTRAINTS
# Limit total power
prob += lpSum([power[i][j]*x[i][j] for j in S for i in N]) <= target_power      

# At most one state active for each machine
for i in N:
    prob += lpSum([x[i][j] for j in S]) <= 1

# Max. total active machines
prob += lpSum(x) <= max_machines

# SOLVE & SHOW RESULTS
prob.solve()
print(LpStatus[prob.status])
print('obj = ' + str(value(prob.objective)))
print('power = ' + str(target_power - value(prob.objective)))

for i in N:
    state = sum((j+1)*x[i][j].varValue for j in S)
    if state > 0: 
        print('Machine %s = %d' %(i+1, state))
```

Result would be shown like:

```
Optimal
obj = 0.0
power = 2500.0
Machine 1 = 3
Machine 2 = 1
Machine 5 = 2
```